# How to send big psd by webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I want to sending by webservice/ WCF big files like 2gb psd.

Is WCF message streaming the best way to cope with this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are, a client-server design which exchanges huge amounts of data like 2GB files indicates a problem with the design. Consider these alternatives:

- Don't send 2GB across the wire, you'll tie up the client during the upload, you might lose the file in transit, etc etc etc. Maybe send a URL to your service instead, so the service can download the file and handle any problems it encounters on the server side.
- For huge amounts of data, client-server might be a totally inappropriate way to process your data. You might be better moving processing to the client side instead of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like msmq transport if you want to send something that large via WCF, that way you can ensure delivery.